# How does the emoji app change the keyboard

Tags: ios, emoji

How does the emoji app modify the default apple keyboard? I thought apple kept the keyboard off limits for developers...

Comment: No third party app (if that's what you mean) can modify any standard iOS keyboard. An app might find a way to make a keyboard look different within the app, but not for other apps.

Comment: But I can use the emojis in email, texting, online, etc... How is that? Is the app still active in the background?

Comment: iOS has an Emoji keyboard built-in. No other app is involved.

Comment: What is "the emoji app"?

Comment: @rmaddy - You are correct, although Fleksy has gotten pretty darn close! (Devs have to include support in their app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between IOS  2.2 - 5.0, the emoji keyboard was only available when you selected the Japanese keyboard and added the key 'EmojiEverywhere' to Preferences.plist.

Now anyone can turn the setting on: Setting:General:Keyboards: select 'add new keyboard' and choose 'Emoji'